# Pass parameters in plain html from spring mvc

Tags: html, spring-mvc

Is there any way i can use Spring MVC to pass parameters to plain html or i have to use jsp only ?

I purchased a theme and all the files in the theme are html,js and css.
Now i want to use spring mvc in my project , but i don't know how to pass parameters  from **spring mvc to plain html files** .I am well aware of JSTL tags in jsp but it won't work in plain html.

I tried below :

`<a href="/viewClass/${param1}">`  but this dosen't work

Shall i use thymeleaf for an existing theme ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for your question is **YES**.

JSPs a bit old thing which had so many drawbacks.

Thymeleaf works smoothly with html.

Comment: thanks man .. I am using thymeleaf now and it works perfectly